# Seeking alternative to Andoid File Transfer utility

Tags: usb, security, file-transfer

Need usb alternative to Android File Transfer for Mac. Problems: 1. no search capability 2. Cannot report size of files. 3. No route to send problem reports to developer. Reasons for not using bluetooth: security.

Answer (score -2):

You can use adb push/pull, it is command line based but working well. You can search using an adb shell.

Comment: And that offers 1. search capability, 2. report size of files, and 3. a way to send reports to the dev? Never heard that, nor did I see it when using `adb push` / `adb pull`.